# Adding space and making sure that they aligned after break

Tags: sed, text-formatting

I am trying to add space in between two strings and making sure that they aligned after every break tried with sed, but it seems to add space after the colon, and that didnt work out because the length of the text before colon varies

EX:

```
Name of user: test1

    username:test1
    User ID:1004 
    Group ID:1004
```

What I want

```
Name of user: test1

        username:     test1
        User ID:      1004 
        Group ID:     1004
```

code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Name of user: test1" 
echo 
echo -n "username" 
getent passwd test1 | cut -d ':' -f 1
echo -n "username" 
getent passwd test1 | cut -d ':' -f 2
echo -n "username" 
getent passwd test1 | cut -d ':' -f 3
```

Comment: `printf` or tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is output that is produced by a script that you can change, just output a tab after the `:` characters when you print the line.

---

Using GNU `sed` (which understands `\t`):

```
$ sed 's/: */:\t/' file
Name of user:   test1

    username:   test1
    User ID:    1004
    Group ID:   1004
```

This just replaces the `:` characters and any spaces after them with a `:` followed by a tab character.

For non-GNU `sed` (e.g. on BSD systems), use a literal tab instead of `\t`. You insert a literal tab on the command line with <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: posted the code I used. When I try to add sed 's/: */:\t/' to the echo it makes space but I it didn't align with the rest

Comment: Nvm the Tab thing worked well ty